# kafka remove content from topic index files

Tags: apache-spark, apache-kafka

I am testing kafka integration with spark as consumer. For debugging , have set-up log.retention.minutes = 2 in server.properties which cleans up .log file every 2mins. But .index file is not cleaned up

```
[cloudera@quickstart airline1-1]$ ls -l
total 0
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 10485760 Apr 29 15:08 00000000000000000101.index
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root        0 Apr 29 15:08 00000000000000000101.log
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 10485756 Apr 29 15:08 00000000000000000101.timeindex
```

Wondering why .index files are not cleaned up. Any insight would be helpful to understand what's happening in the background.

Also please share recommended approach to clean up log and index during testing. Found many google links referring to stop kakfa server -> remove topic partition files -> Restart kafka.  But not inclined towards this approach , it could impact offsets state maintained in zookeeper.

Thanks very much!

Comment: Offsets are no longer maintained in Zookeeper by default.  The 0.10.x versions of Kafka maintain the offsets in Kafka itself.

Comment: Index files should also be removed. Did you find out that .index and .timeindex files still existed although .log file was deleted?

Comment: index files are not getting emptied , only log file size becomes 0. Seems like log.retention.minutes parm not related to cleaning up index files